# Javascript validation to allow only string followed by number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to restrict the user to enter in textbox only string followed by number only for e.g

```
AA1->true
AA1A->False
AA12->True
AB12AA14AB->false
12AA->false
ABC12->false
AA->false
```

So please let me know how can I add validation for above condition/cases using javascript.

Comment: Do you want to know **how to validate this**, or do you want to get an idea **how js code can know if the input is valid**?

Comment: learn about regex in jquery or javascrit.. it will help you more

Comment: validate by regex is what you need. try ```[A-Z]+[0-9]+``` for example

Comment: `ABC12` is a alphabetical characters followed by numeric characters, shouldn't it be `true` as well?

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression:

```js
const validate = str => /^[A-Z]+\d+$/.test(str);
`AA1
AA1A
AA12
AB12AA14AB
12AA
ABC12
AA`
  .split('\n')
  .forEach(str => console.log(validate(str)));
```

`^` indicates the start of the string, `[A-Z]+` matches one or more uppercase alphabetical characters, `\d+` matches one or more numbers, and `$` matches the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

`function isStrEndWithNum(str){
   if(str)
      return !isNaN(str[str.length-1]);
   return false;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .test function which is present in JavaScript

```
/^([\w]+[0-9])$/.test('YourStringHere');
```

i am just confused with second last condition of yours.

Other than that all your conditions are passed with the above code.

Comment: my second last condition is don’t allow consecutive alphabets followed by number like ABC12

Comment: Using above code if I enter in textbox like 'aa1212dd12' it allows.In my case it don't allow.Only aa12,BB45 allow.

Comment: Sorry for the Late reply but i think this will resolve the issue
/^([A-Z]{1})(\d{1})|([A-Z]{1})(\d{2})|([A-Z]{2})(\d{1})|([A-Z]{2})(\d{2})|([A-Z]{3})(\d{1})$/.test("Your String Here")